# GROUP BY is returning wrong values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written the following query but it is not grouping correctly on dates and returns 2 rows which should actually be combined into one by the `GROUP BY`.

```
select i.overridedate,
       month(i.Overridedate), 
       count(i.id)as count,
       sum(case when oi.rating <50 then 1 else 0 end) as unfav,
       sum(case when oi.Rating =50  then 1 else 0 end) as neu,
       sum(case when oi.Rating >50  then 1 else 0 end) as fav,
       avg(oi.Rating)as 'Av Rating'
from Items i (nolock)

inner join ItemOrganisations oi (nolock) on i.ID= oi.ItemID
inner join Lookup_ItemTypes it (nolock) on it.ID = i.ItemTypeID
inner join Batches b (nolock) on b.ID=i.BatchID
inner join Lookup_ItemStatus lis (nolock) on lis.ID = i.StatusID
inner join Lookup_BatchStatus lbs (nolock) on lbs.ID = b.StatusID
inner join Lookup_BatchTypes bt on bt.id = b.Typeid

where lbs.Name = 'Completed by Analyst'
      or lbs.Name='Delivered/Imported into Neptune Online'
      and lis.Name = 'Complete'
      and i.IsRelevant = 1
      and bt.Name = 'Live'
    group by i.overridedate, Month(i.OverrideDate)
    having i.OverrideDate between '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2012-09-30 00:00:00.000'
```

As you can see, the last two rows which represent the data for month 7 are not grouped by:

```
NULL       NULL             1     0     1     0     1     55
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000     1     1     1     0     0     10
2012-05-28 00:00:00.000     5     7     1     0     1     50
2012-06-01 00:00:00.000     6     7     1     0     0     20
2012-07-10 00:00:00.000     7     1     0     0     0     NULL
2012-07-11 00:00:00.000     7     8     1     0     6     66
```

Comment: Remove i.overridedate from your SELECT and GROUP BY statements.  Add YEAR if needed.

Comment: @sgeddes comments like that should be posted as answers ;-)

Comment: @sgeddes That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Could someone show me an example please, Im stuck ;(

Comment: Sorry for not posting as an answer -- foosball was a calling and I didn't have time to format something a little nicer :D

Comment: Delete the i.override from the select and group.  Move the having up and make it a where.

Comment: @sgeddes The question changed while you were playing foosball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `group by` is correct.  Why are you including the override date in it?

Perhaps your select should be:

```
select min(i.overridedate), month(i.Overridedate),
. . . 
group by month(i.Overridedate)
```

And, I strongly agree with the comments that say to include the year:

```
select min(i.overridedate), year(i.Overridedate), month(i.Overridedate),
. . . 
group by year(i.Overridedate), month(i.Overridedate)
```

Comment: I have a having clause on the query and forgot to include, basically im passing in two date ranges but cannot group by these date ranges as it does not allow me to group by outer references, any idea how i can accomplish this?

Comment: @xerxes . . . I think you should post that as a separate question.  It is quite different from this question.